# Initializing struct value with function

Tags: swift, init

I have a Swift struct which has a `title` property. In my initializer, I can set the property as normal. If, however, I want to extract the logic for its value to another function, I get a compiler warning.

This works:

```
init(document: MyDocument) {
    documentIdentifier = document.documentIdentifier
    createDate = document.createDate
    title = "A Title"
}
```

This fails:

```
    title = generateTitle(forDocument: document)
```

The compiler says `Variable 'self.title' used before being initialized`. If I put a static setter just above this line, the error goes away. My generate function returns a non-optional value. What's the compiler grumpy about?

Answer (score 2):

`generateTitle` is an instance method, but the instance itself isn't yet created before the initialiser returns and hence you cannot call any methods on it. If you really want to extract the setup code for `title` into a separate method and you aren't actually accessing any instance properties from that method, you can make it `static` and hence accessible even from the `init`.

Comment: Thank you, of course! A more helpful error message would have made this easier to realise my mistake.